# Using textscan in Matlab on .csv files

Tags: matlab

I was hoping someone might be able to help me with reading in a file with textscan (or some other function in Matlab).  The documentation and examples online have been no help to me and I guess I am missing something intuitive :(  Here is what the structure of the file I want to read in looks like:

```
ID,  Date of ID,    C 1-1,  C 1-2,  M R3,   M R4,   Glob ID Settings
TPOL_430_412_10X,   5/5/2011 20:23, 0,  0,  0,  0,  -1, 5.00_5.00_3_300.00_3_0.00
TPOL_430_412_10X,   5/5/2011 20:23, 0,  0,  0,  0,  -1, 5.00_5.00_3_300.00_3_0.00
TPOL_430_412_10X,   5/5/2011 20:23, 0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  5.00_5.00_3_300.00_3_0.00
TPOL_430_412_10X,   5/5/2011 20:23  0,  0,  0,  0,  -1, 5.00_5.00_3_300.00_3_0.00
TPOL_430_412_10X,   5/5/2011 20:23  0,  0,  0,  0,  -1, 5.00_5.00_3_300.00_3_0.00
```

Where my file is a .csv file so the delimiter is a comma.  What I have been trying to no avail is the following:

```
fmt = [repmat('%s',1,2), repmat('%f',1,5),'%*s %[^\n]'];
fid = fopen('file.csv','rt');
data = textscan(fid, fmt, 'HeaderLines', 1);
fclose(fid);
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you want to read from the last column?

Comment: So the last column is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this

```
A = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %f %f %f %f %f %s', 'HeaderLines', 1);
```

it should split all the parameters you want to read into a cell `A` with size `(1,9)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also needed to specify the delimiter, that was actually my problem :)