# Textscan generates a vectore twice the expected size

Tags: matlab, csv

I want to load a csv file in a matrix using matlab.

I used the following code:

```
formatSpec = ['%*f', repmat('%f',1,20)];

fid = fopen(filename);
X = textscan(fid, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', ',', 'CollectOutput', 1);
fclose(fid);
X = X{1};
```

The csv file has 1000 rows and 21 columns.
However, the matrix X generated has 2000 columns and 20 columns.

I tried using different delimiters like '\t' or '\n', but it doesn't change.
When I displayed X, I noticed that it displayed the correct csv file but with extra rows of zeros every 2 rows.

I also [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735053/using-textscan-in-matlab-on-csv-files) adding the 'HeaderLines' parameters:

```
`X = textscan(fid, formatSpec1, 'Delimiter', '\n', 'CollectOutput', 1, 'HeaderLines', 1);`
```

but this time, the result is an empty matrix.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT: @horchler**

I could read with no problem the 'test.csv' file.
There is no extra comma at the end of each row. I generated my csv file with a python script: I read the rows of another csv file, modified these (selecting some of them and doing arithmetic operations on them) and wrote the new rows on another csv file. In order to do this, I converted each element of the first csv file into floats...

**New Edit**:
Reading the textscan documentation more carefully, I think the problem is that my input file is neither a textfile nor a str, but a file containing floats

**EDIT: three lines from the file**

0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,2
1,-0.3834323,-1.92452324171,-1.2453254094,0.43455627857,-0.24571121,0.4340657,1,1,0,0,0,0.3517396202,1,0,0,0.3558122164,0.2936975319,0.4105696144,0,1,0
-0.78676,-1.09767,0.765554578,0.76579043,0.76,1,0,0,323124.235998,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,2

Comment: How was your CSV file created? Do you possibly have a trailing comma at the end of each row? If your write a file with 100 rows and a 21 columns via `dlmwrite('test.csv',rand(1e3,21),',')` can you read it in as expected?

Comment: @horchler please look at the edited question

Comment: Upload your file somewhere and paste the link here so that we can give it a try.

Comment: Try adding `%*s` to the end of `formatSpec` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @OlegKomarov I can't send the whole file, but when I tried to extract part of the file and save it in another csv file, I didn't have this problem. Therefore, I think the problem is with the delimiter. Is there any way to know what delimiter a csv file uses?

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia: I tried adding %*s, it didn't change the result

Comment: Can you open the csv with notepad and paste here a couple of lines?

Comment: So it would be helpful if you provide one or two lines of the file.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia and Oleg: Please look at the last edit.

Comment: first and third lines have 21 elements but the second one has 22 elements. I used `formatSpec = ['%*f' repmat('%f',1,20) '%*s']` and it worked fine.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia thanks. The problem came indeed from the wrong number of lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using regex ?

```
X=[];
fid = fopen(filename);
while 1
  fl = fgetl(fid);
  if ~ischar(fl),   break,   end
  r =regexp(fl,'([-]*\d+[.]*\d*)','match');
  r=r(1:21); % because your line 2nd is somehow having 22 elements, 
  % all lines must have same # elements or an error will be thrown
  % Error: CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
  X=[X;r];
end
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [csvread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) to read a csv file seems a good option. However, I also tend to read csv files with textscan as files are sometimes badly written.  Having more options to read them is therefore necessary.

I face a reading problem like yours when I think the file is written a certain way but it is actually written another way. To debug it I use [fgetl](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) and print, for each line read, both the output of fgetl and its [double](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) version (see the example below). Examining the double version, you may find which character causes a problem.

In your case, I would first look at multiple occurrences of delimiters (',' and '\t') and , in 'textscan', I would activate the option 'MultipleDelimsAsOne' (while turning off 'CollectOutput').

```
fid = fopen(filename);

tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)

    disp(tline);
    double(tline)
    pause;

    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

Comment: I ran the code you sent me. However, for a strange reason, the numbers that are displayed are not the numbers in the csv file at all... I also tried changing the delimiter (I think this is the source of the problem) with ',', '\t', '\n', but still the same problem...

Comment: double('1':'9') gives you the acsii code of the digits in their string forms. You don't have the same numbers because digit 1 is coded 49, digit 2 is coded 50... and commas are coded 44. In your output, you must only have 44, and 49 to 57 as you have only commas and digits. If you have numbers such as 32 (space) or 10 (tabulation), they may be the cause of the reading failure.